# Responsive CSS margin

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

The goal is to accomplish this:

[image]

1) The black box represents a div (#black_box).

2) At a width of 1000px, the div has a negative margin and is clipped by the viewport.

3) At another width, 2000px, the negative margin is replaced by a positive margin.

4) So far the html/css looks like so:

```
<section>
    <div id="content">
        [SOME STUFF]
        <div id="black_box">
            [SOME STUFF]
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

section { margin: 0; padding: 5%; }
#black_box { margin-left: -5%; padding: 5% 5% 5% 10%; }
```

Now with viewport size increase:

```
section { margin-left: 10%; padding: 5%; }
#black_box { margin: 0; padding: 5%; }
```

I know there's an easy way to test viewport width with jQuery, but can you specify a range? Like viewport = 300px-1000px do this else viewport = 1001px+ do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you after a js-only solution? Because otherwise you can use max-width and min-width media queries.

Comment: CSS solutions are perfectly fine. I was just assuming CSS couldn't handle it or a CSS solution would not be that great cross-browser. But if you have a CSS only way, by all means, let me know and I will check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use media queries in css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
    your css for width 2000
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        your css for width 1000
}
```

Comment: Wow, talk about a serious disconnect. I'm already using this for some iPhone/iPad CSS and it didn't even cross my mind I could be using it here too. I guess it's just too late. I'll give it a shot and see what I come up with. Thanks.

Comment: You can combine your min and max media queries too, e.g.
   @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1000px)